# I am not able to select the dropdown using selenium webdriver please

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to select the drop down of this site and proceed to buy a show, but I am not able to do so please help.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();              
 driver.get("http://www.theatrepeople.com/");

 driver.findElement(By.id("edit-show")).click();

 new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("edit-show"))).selectByVisibleText("The 39 Steps");
 driver.findElement(By.id("edit-date-datepicker-popup-0")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("27")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("edit-ticket-no")).click();
 new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("edit-ticket-no"))).selectByVisibleText("1 ticket");
 driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit-1")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code. It uses java script to select a text based upon it's valued. Really nice question. I also got to learn.

```
static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\ToCustomer_31_5_13\\src\\main\\resources\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();              
          driver.get("http://www.theatrepeople.com/");

          driver.findElement(By.id("edit-show")).click();
          WebElement show = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'edit-show-wrapper']//div[@id = 'showNameWrap']"));
          List<WebElement> l = show.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
          String valueToSelect = getAttibuteValueForShow(l, "The American Plan");         
           driver.findElement(By.id("mini-basket-ajax")).click();
          selectValueInDropDown(valueToSelect);       
    }


    public static String getAttibuteValueForShow(List<WebElement> li, String showName)
    {
        int j =0;
        String value = null;
         for(int i =0; i<li.size(); i++)
         {
             j = j +1;
             String dropDownText = li.get(i).getText();
             if(dropDownText.equalsIgnoreCase(showName))
             {
                value =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'edit-show-wrapper']//div[@id = 'showNameWrap']//option[" + j +"]")).getAttribute("value");
                System.out.println(value);
                 break;
             }
         }
         return value;
    }

    public static void selectValueInDropDown(String value)
    {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
         String jsCmd = "document.getElementsByName('show')[0].value='" + value + "'";
         js.executeScript(jsCmd);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vinay it is working fine now. But it works only on Firefox. Tried with other browser's it doesn't work. I have used the same code only changed the Driver details. I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: It worked with chrome and firefox for me. Let me check it out and get back tomorrow.

Comment: Have changed the code a bit. Will work on any browser. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to click on the *select* form (`driver.findElement(By.id("edit-show")).click()`), you just want to select an element (using the `Select` class). This is also probably the reason why your code is not working. You should remove this line and it should work.

Comment: I removed driver.findElement(By.id("edit-show")).click(); still it is not able to select the show The 39 Steps and it stops throwing error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (827, 251). Other element would receive the click: <option value="1667">...</option>

Comment: I am not able to select a Show and that is stopping me to proceed to next step

Comment: Have you tried finding the bounding `form` element first? `Webelement form = driver.findElement(By.id("booking-theatre-people-show-search-form")); select = new Select(form.findElement(By.id("edit-show"));` In a few cases I've noticed I've had to do this - no idea why but it's helped me out of a few jams before.

Comment: @LaurentG : thnx for the ans.  But i want to know to show the user that drop down list is up for selection and preferred option is selected and then sets as the default value again in the dropdown. Can u help in this plz?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

```
     driver.get("http://www.theatrepeople.com/");
     WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("edit-ticket-no"));
     Select sel = new Select(dropDown);
     sel.selectByVisibleText("1 ticket");
```

Comment: I am not able to select a Show and that is stopping me to proceed to next step